# Refresh page each time you load via javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a web app that utilizes JQuery. In my javascript I have a function called by an onclick event in my HTML that triggers this function:

```
$('#secondPage').load('pages/calendar.html');
```

The html file that it calls contains javascript that loads in from a .json file. The problem is, is that when you leave the page via javascript, when you go back to the calendar.html page, it is cached so it does not refresh from the .json file.

Is there a way to add something in that will call a refresh on that page or from the .json? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what method you use to load JSON content in calendar.html but I'm assuming you are using jQuery function.

You can use jQuery.ajax() to load JSON content and set cache to be false so that the browser does not cache the result:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will do it, but to avoid caching the AJAX calls, I use random params.

Browsers cache calls that have the same parameters values. So I add a random parameter to my calls, just so the browser doesn't cache them. It is just for that, I don't use that parameter on anything.

You could do something like this:

```
$('#secondPage').load('pages/calendar.html?random=' + Math.random());
```

Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely useful:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

It disables caching on ajax calls made by jquery.